# Share content using ShareCompat

Tags: java, android

I have a strange problem when I try to share a my_file.html using ShareCompat.
As best practice I have created my own FileProvider but I get the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /forms/Proof_of_Life_Form.html` I think I have set up all of the stuff correctly.

My XML I have created a provider for that.

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.douglas.sample"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
</provider>
```

This is my `filepaths` created in `res/xml/filepaths`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <paths>
        <cache-path path="/forms" name="forms" />
    </paths>
```

and also my method that is responsible to call share content.

```
    public void shareContent() {
            File file = new File("/forms/", fileName + ".html");
            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), "com.douglas.sample", file);
            Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(getActivity())
                    .setType(getActivity().getContentResolver().getType(uri))
                    .setStream(uri)
                    .getIntent();
            //Provide read access
            shareIntent.setData(uri);
            shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getString(R.string.share_form)));
        }
```

Finally my exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /forms/Proof_of_Life_Form.html
                                                                                at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:719)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:404)
                                                                                at com.douglas.sample.TabbedFormsFragment$2.run(TabbedFormsFragment.java:254)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Any Idea? thanks :D

Comment: Is that a mistype in your `filepaths.xml` file? It says `<file-pat`

Comment: @ianhanniballake that's true but I fixed and continue :(

Answer (score 1):

It seems there are some little mistakes in your code.

Try the following:

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.FileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

and then in your provider_paths.xml try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
<!-- We would like to give access to the External Storage of the app.
     external_files will expose the path app to storage/emulated/0/ and the
     "." is to actually point the root folder. The final path of the Uri will start
     from path above and whatever folder we defined. For application upgrades
     will be external_files/Android/data/package name/files/updates/name of update apk.-->
<external-path
    name="external_files"
    path="."/>
</paths>
```

and then whereever you want to use it try:

```
String path = Uri.parse(your_file_uri).getPath();
FileProvider.getUriForFile(application, PROVIDER, new File(path)),my_file_type);
```

where my_file_type = e.g. "application/vnd.android.package-archive" for .apk file

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Actually, my little mistake was about my path like this: File file = new File(context.getCacheDir(), fileName + ".html"); and then works well o/